# How Parse JSON String in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I want to know something about JSON and MYSQL:

1. It can be Possible to store JSON values to Mysql Database.
2. If we can store JSON String to Mysql DB then can we able to process or parse Stored JSON in mysql?

Comment: 1. It is possible since it is just a string 2. Why to do that actually?

Comment: You can store and process JSON as VARCHAR or BLOB. If you are looking for parsing and/or MapReduce, then the answer is No, MySql cannot do that. Consider CouchDB or MongoDb.

Answer (score 0):

To store any JSON object into SQL database you can simply create a text columns to save the JSON string representation and parse it using 'LIKE' operator.

On the other hand, you can use an auxiliar table to save key/values pairs and using foreign keys to reference the key/values of each JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 5.7.8, MySQL added the JSON Data Type. So I believe now you can easily store, manipulate JSON values using MySQL.